# Single fundamental force at Planck epoch?

Tags: forces, universe

It is hypothese that after big bang when universe is a Planck time old, the 4 known fundamental forces used to be equal in strength or perhaps there existed single fundamental force before splitting off. Is it true that if we can achieve Planck temperature we might see this single fundamental force?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is simple - yes. There is a nice picture illustrating the idea of the grand unification.[image]